# How to return the inner text representing the Site Address

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Im fairly new to XML coding and need some help with a LINQ query that will allow me to return the String the represents the Site Address in the XML response shown in the image below:

```
<Response>
  <Status>OK</Status> 
  <CustomFields>
    <CustomField>
      <ID>1</ID> 
      <Name>Date Field</Name> 
      <Date>2010-10-11T00:00:00</Date> 
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
      <ID>2</ID> 
      <Name>Number Field</Name> 
      <Number>123</Number> 
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
      <ID>3</ID> 
      <Name>Delivery Address</Name> 
      <Text>176 Monash Avenue, Nedlands</Text> 
    </CustomField>
  </CustomFields>
</Response>
```

The XML is the response to an REST GET query for our cloud based job costing system. The code I have so far is shown below. This actually works to return a list and then I have to iterate through the list until I find the Site Address (Delivery Address). I was hoping there was a way to do this more simply by accessing the element containing "Delivery Address" directly?

```
List<CustomField> customfield = new List<CustomField>();
            string endpoint = "https://api.workflowmax.com/job.api/get/"+ jobnum + "/customfield?apiKey=" + API_Key + "&accountKey=" + Account_Key;
            var client = new RestClient(endpoint: endpoint, method: HttpVerb.GET);
            var json = client.MakeRequest();
            string response = json;


        //load the unparsed string into an XML document
        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
        xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);

        customfield =
                xdoc.Root
                    .Descendants("CustomFields")
                    .Select(n =>
                        new CustomField
                        {
                            ID = (string)n.Element("ID"),
                            Name = (string)n.Element("Name"),
                            Text = (string)n.Element("Client").Element("ID"),
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: how does the xml look like?

Comment: Just like in the image I posted.

Comment: Paste it as XML here.

Comment: Update: I have created a class that represents a CustomField. Then I created a list of this class. I can now retrieve all of the custom fields and then use LINQ to find the field with the Site Address but I was hoping there was a simpler way of doing it...??

Comment: where is the delivery address?

Comment: <Response>
  <Status>OK</Status> 
  <CustomFields>
    <CustomField>
      <ID>1</ID> 
      <Name>Date Field</Name> 
      <Date>2010-10-11T00:00:00</Date> 
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
      <ID>2</ID> 
      <Name>Number Field</Name> 
      <Number>123</Number> 
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
      <ID>3</ID> 
      <Name>Site Address</Name> 
      <Decimal>34 Monash Avenue, Nedlands</Decimal> 
    </CustomField>
  </CustomFields>
</Response>

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, ill update the original post with the XML, Also the Site Address = Delivery Address. One sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath to extract the `Text` value in a `CustomField` of name `Site Address`.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath; // contains extension method XPathSelectElement

/* ... */

XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);

string address = xdoc
    .XPathSelectElement("Response/CustomFields/CustomField[Name = 'Delivery Address']/Text")
    .Value;
```

Here is a good XPath tutorial at [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: Hi Yeldar, thanks for your reply. This looks like a neat solution but I cant access the .XpathSelectElement. It isnt a method under xdoc for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: p.s I got lazy copying the XML and took a sample and edited it hence the <decimal> :) fixed now.

Comment: @Will It is an extension method. Add `using System.Xml.XPath;`.

Comment: Thanks dude! very helpful. Nice neat solution and all working :) Cheers!

Comment: @Will Nice to hear it. You may accept the answer if it was helpful :)